# How to receive wifi networks scan on android 7

Tags: android, android-7.0-nougat, android-7.1-nougat

I am working on an application that needs to get the wifi scanned networks, so I get it in the android's common way. I register a receiver in the manifest file with the intent filter for the action SCAN_RESULTS.

That has been working fine for previous android versions but in android 7 that is not working nor will work on android 8, specifically in android 7 I do not get the wifi scan, so my application doesn't work.

Is there a way in android 7 to get the wifi scan? I don't need to get it as soon as I did in the previous versions.

thanks